# preprocessor directive not working

Tags: c

I made a program which removes spaces and makes a string upper case by preprocessor directives .its not changing to uppercase

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
# define TOUPPER(x) (x-32)
void main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    char str[100],*p;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    gets(str);
    for(i=0;    ;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='\0')
        break;
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            for(j=i;    ;j++)
            {
             str[j]=str[j+1];
             if(str[j]=='\0')
             break;
            }
         }
         if(str[i]<='a'||str[i]>='z')
         {
            *p=str[i];
            TOUPPER('p');

         }


        }
        puts(str);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you aren't using the `islower` and `toupper` library functions?

Comment: I am told to do by preprocessor directives.
(Preprocessor directives work faster than functions)

Comment: Thanks alot!As much as my knowledege says something like this should also work:
TOUPPER(&str[i]);
but it never does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you do

```
TOUPPER('p');
```

and it is defined as

```
(x-32)
```

This changes 'p' to upper-case but don't save it.

You need to change you define like this

```
#define TOUPPER(x) ((*x)=((*x)-32))
```

just do call it like this:

```
TOUPPER(p);
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `TOUPPER('p')` does exactly what it should, nothing.  You're subtracting 32 from the numeric value of `'p'` and then throwing it away.  Note that I'm referring to 'p' the character, not `p` the pointer.

Comment: Thanks alot!As much as my knowledege says something like this should also work:
TOUPPER(&str[i]);
but it never does work.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is wrong range condition, Macro call with constant argument and you are not assigning the value back.

```
if(str[i]<='a'||str[i]>='z')
         {
            *p=str[i];
            TOUPPER('p');

         }
```

Correction:

```
if(str[i]>='a'||str[i]<='z')
         {
            str[i] = TOUPPER(str[i]);
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you wanted:

```
str[i]=TOUPPER(str[i])
```

(And don't mess around with those pointer p)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't what you're asking, but please note you have a serious pointer error in your program:

```
char str[100],*p;

  ...

if(str[i]<='a'||str[i]>='z')
     {
        *p=str[i];
        TOUPPER('p');

     }
```

The pointer `p` is uninitialized (can be pointing to anywhere in memory), and you are assigning the character str[i] to that pointer's memory location. `p` might be equal to 0x00000000 or 0xCDCDCDCD or something else, but in any case you are writing str[i] to that location without initializing p to an appropriate address.

If you feel you must use pointers, you could do it this way (still doesn't fix the range issue that others mentioned, the `<=` and `>=` are backwards):

```
if (str[i]<='a'||str[i]>='z')
{
   p=&str[i]; // p now points to the address of str[i]
   *p = TOUPPER(*p); // p = the address, *p = the contents of that address
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe that using preprocessor macros is always faster than using the functions from `<ctype.h>`. It is highly probable that these functions are in fact implemented as preprocessor macros themselves. Just write code that is easy to understand, and only "optimize" it if it is necessary.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void
str_toupper(char *str)
{
    char *p;

    for (p = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        if (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) {
            memmove(p + 0, p + 1, strlen(p) - 1);
        }
        *p = toupper((unsigned char) *p);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];

    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the string:\n");
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL)
        return 0;

    str_toupper(str);

    printf("%s\n", str);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```